# Meaning of “very confined"

Tags: understanding

What does "Very confined” mean in this short news update?

> Shortly after news of the fire broke, Trump, who was in Washington,
>   tweeted: “Fire at Trump Tower is out. **Very confined** (well built
>   building). Firemen (and women) did a great job.

Comment: "Very confined" sounds a little strange in this context to this US English speaker - either the fire was confined, or it wasn't.  But President Trump is not known for an excellent command of the English language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tweet means that the fire was confined to a small area of the building, likely implying that little damage was done to the building's structure and the units surrounding where the fire started.

You can interpret the entire thing more broadly as:

> The fire at Trump Tower is out. It [the fire] was very confined in area due to the building being well built.